# Repo URL of all jobs through jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to get the git scm url for a Jenkins job with groovy in the Jenkins script console?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding what you've tried so far, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: i am trying to parse the config.xml inorder to get the repo url but getting the following error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
 at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:207)
 at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:260)
 at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parseText(XmlSlurper.java:286)

Comment: Could you share your code and error in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("JOB_NAME")
println item.getScm().getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
```

If you want to iterate over all jobs that support Git you can use following script:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.AbstractProject.class).each {it -> 
  scm = it.getScm()
  if(scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM)
  {
    println scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
  }
}
println "Done"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment and is there a possiblity for also listing out the jobs from a repository. kindly do guide. thanks

Comment: Hi Krzysztof Błażełek,    Jenkins.instance.getAllItems().each {it ->
   if(it instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) {
              item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(it.fullName)
              println item.getScm().getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()}}

Comment: I've added example script that iterates over all jobs that support GitSCM and prints their remote url.

Comment: This saved me so much time! I wonder whether I should tell my boss I'm free or pretend I've been working hard combing through the hundreds of jobs.